# Not able to play filename.avi file in VLC

Tags: video, vlc

I got a video which was playing on the sender's laptop. When I downloaded it and tried playing using VLC, the duration of the video was shown as 0.00 with no error popping up.

I tried a `file --mime-type filename.avi` which gave the result as `filename.avi: application/octet-stream`.

I tried `mediainfo filename.avi` and the result was only the full name and the size information as below

```
General
Complete name           : filename.avi
File size               : 617 MiB
```

`file filename.avi` gives an output as `filename.avi: data`.

I have installed `ubuntu-restricted-extras` as well which doesn't help.

What could be the issue here? Is there any workaround for viewing this in VLC player? Or is there any player which I can try to play this video?

Comment: This looks like the video got corrupted during sending. Can you play other .avi files?

Comment: Like others mentioned already : file might have got corrupted during download. If you have downloaded from a torrent, it is also possible that the torrent is fake and the file you downloaded is a dummy data file.

Comment: Yes able to play other .avi files. It was not a torrent download, the person which shared it with me has the video running in his laptop. He shared through cloud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The video has possibly got corrupted while sending. To confirm this you can check the `md5sum` or `sha256sum` values of both the files. In case the file is corrupted, it would have different values than that of the original.

To check `md5sum` values open a terminal and go to the directory in which the file is located. Run `md5sum filename.avi`. This will produce the `md5sum` value of the file. Repeat the process for copied file. Alternatively, you can redirect the output to a file using `md5sum filename.avi > md5dum.txt` and then copy the file to the same location where the new file and check it there using `md5sum -c md5sum.txt`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately I got the file through multiple transmissions from a customer. Since I don't have direct contact, wont be able to request them to run a check. But I assume this is the issue.